# Why are spaces in Edittext if clicked in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

If I click on my empty edittext I can see that the cursor jumps 2-3 spaces forward.
Why is it so?

I don't do anything with it programatically.

Maybe something in XML-Code is wrong. Can someone tell me why it starts with 3 spaces?

```
                <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/textfield"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingRight="30dp" />
```

Comment: You mean you can press back and delete the white spaces?

Comment: it works fine, rest of xml is ok?

Comment: yes i can delete the spaces like i tiped them

Comment: your xml file is ok. I used your xml code cursor blinking at start position there is no any space. Please check in separate  demo

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `android:paddingRight="30dp"` and run the application.